# setTextColor/setTextAppearance doesn't work on programmatically added TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I have been trying to create my table dynamically, by adding TextView to linear layout as header of list.

I'm trying to set my TextView's text color to white (code is below) but it's same black text anyway.

My TextView wrapper:

```
public static class HeaderTextView implements HeaderBox {

    Context mContext;

    TextView textView;
    protected String text;

    public HeaderTextView(Context context, String text, int widthCoefficient) {
        this.text = text;
        this.mContext = context;

        textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
        textView.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Medium);

        textView.setLayoutParams(
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        Sizer.dpAsPixels(
                                context,
                                widthCoefficient * Grid.COLUMN_WIDTH
                        ),
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )
        );

        textView.setText(text);

    }

public View toView() {
    return textView;
}
```

Used by another function:

```
public static View createGridHeader(Context context, HeaderBox... columns) {
    LinearLayout tableHeader = new LinearLayout(context);

    tableHeader.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    tableHeader.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    ));
    tableHeader.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    tableHeader.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    for(int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        tableHeader.addView(columns[i].toView());
    }

    return tableHeader;
}
```

In the end, I'm adding those views to a LinearLayout by that:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ListView raporList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_rapor);
    LinearLayout raporHeader = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_linear);

    raporHeader.addView(
            Grid.createGridHeader(
                    getContext(),
                    new Grid.HeaderEditBox(getContext(), "TEEEEST", 4),
                    new Grid.HeaderEditBox(getContext(), "Teeest 2", 14),
                    new Grid.HeaderTextView(getContext(), "DENEME :)", 4)
            ),0
    );

    view.invalidate();

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Neither setTextColor or setTextAppearance seems to work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just for testing, instead of `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white)` use `Color.RED` for example

Comment: I tried Color.WHITE instead, didn't work also

Comment: what is the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top`?

Comment: and for testing use `Color.RED` and remove `setTextAppearance`, try that first

Comment: @pskink https://gist.github.com/beremaran/e190724bce8dd89d9086bb9dbc9ff718

Comment: I just tried using Color.RED and removing setTextAppearance, nothing changed.

Comment: ok does `setText` work?

Comment: I just changed order of setTextAppearance and setTextColor, and both of them started to work